# Replace words in string beginning with @ symbol

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to replace the words that contain an `@` symbol with a link in php

e.g.:

```
$string = "you would love this @matt";
```

would turn into "`you would love this <a href="/user/matt">@matt</a>`"

From research I need to use `preg_replace()`, but don't know where to start. Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Imr6c4)

```
$string = "you would love this @matt";
$pattern = '/(^|\W)(@([a-zA-Z]+))/';
$replacement = '$1<a href="/user/$3">$2</a>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: Matt, each set of parenthesis are assigned a number.  The first set (\s?) looks for an optional space and it is stored in $1.  The second and third set are the same except #2 will have the `@` symbol in front of it.  $2 will contain `@matt` and $3 will contain `matt`.  Then he just takes each piece and assembles the URL string you are wanting to build.

Comment: This answer is perfect, is there anyway I can ensure that there is a space before the @ symbol?

Comment: @MattEllwood: I just updated the pattern with a better way. If you just made it ensure there is a space before the @ symbol, it would not match the string `@matt would love this`. Instead, change the `\s?` in the pattern to `^|\W`. This will find it if it's at the beginning of the string(`^`) or if it's preceded by a non-word character (`\W`). This way, it will match if the @ symbol is at the beginning of the word, but not if it's in the middle of a word (like an email address).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) for that:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/(?<=\s)@(\w+)/', function($match) {
    return sprintf('<a href="/user/%s">@%s</a>', 
       urlencode($match[1]), 
       $match[1]
    );
}, htmlspecialchars($string));
```

Doing this enables you to do apply additional formatting for each match.